# How to create table B like A with foreign key definitions?

Tags: mysql

I am able to create table `sales_order` in database `archived_db` with the same schema as `sales_order` table from main database `prod_db` using below query:

`CREATE TABLE archived_db.sales_order LIKE prod_db.sales_order`

It is working fine and creating sales_order table in `archived_db` with same table structure as in `prod_db`. One thing that is not copied/created is the foreign key.

so, my question is, is it possible to create table B using schema of table A with the same foreign_keys?

Comment: create a dumb with mysqldunp including triigers and rename the database ind the sql file

Comment: Yes, that is one alternative though I have multiple similar tables and after dumping them I  need to truncate the tables. I want something dynamic so that I can test with multiple databases/tables easily.

Comment: mysql Workbench and phpadmin offer a gui to dumb and create backup scripts

Comment: Do you want to link the FK to the `prod_db` or the `archived_db`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I want to link FK to `prod_db`.

Comment: If it's a one-time-task, then use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` as Bill Karwin suggested and modify the table reference manually. But I feel like you are asking for troubles with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE prod_db.sales_order
```

This shows the table definition in the syntax of a CREATE TABLE statement.

Capture the result of this into a string, and then run that string as an SQL statement.

I would suppose that `CREATE TABLE <B> LIKE <A>` doesn't support foreign keys because foreign keys are a feature that depends on the storage engine. The engine-independent metadata does not store foreign key definitions. This is one of the unexpected consequences of MySQL's strange history and architecture of pluggable storage engines.

---

Re your comment:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Does the parent table exist in the archived db schema in which you are creating the copy table? I imagine the foreign key definition does not qualify the table name, and assumes that the parent table is in the same schema as the `sales_order` table.

If you need to specify which schema the foreign key references, it's probably best to create the table using `CREATE TABLE LIKE` as you were before, and then add foreign key(s) using `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: I rather suspect it's an unwanted feature. Consider you want to "duplicate" parent and child tables. Which table should the new child table reference?

Comment: Running the string output says `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`. It seems I need to specify the database name as well which will be used in FK reference.

Comment: @BillKarwin Parent tables doesn't exist in my archived db. Create table using `LIKE` statement and adding foreign key(s) using `ALTER TABLE` will work for me.